# Error while pulling docker image from ECR to EC2 using github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github-actions, cicd, amazon-ecr

From main.yaml the docker pull command is executed in continoud deployment phase but it throws an error.
This was the error:
`Error response from daemon: repository ***/*** not found: name unknown: The repository with name '***/***' does not exist in the registry with id '***'`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/frDre.png)

Comment: What permissions do the user have?

Comment: I'm the root user and I can able to build and push an image to ECR but pulling the docker image on EC2 gives me this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AWS ECR copy the URI (Universal resource locator) without the registry name.